# How do I hide files inside an image without using any steganography tools?

Tags: steganography

I want to hide files inside a picture. The files may be music or video. Is it technically possible to do this? If so, how?

I searched on Google to find methods.  Please suggest some methods for beginners. I don't know where to start, so please guide me.

***Important note: Modifying the size of an image up to a certain extent e.g.,
before hiding image size: 1MB and after hiding image size can be up to 4MB.***

I referred to the following URLs:

> martinolivier.com/open/stegoverview.pdf
>
> www.garykessler.net/library/steganography.html
>
> www.jjtc.com/ihws98/jjgmu.html
>
> pcplus.techradar.com/.../secrets-of-steganography/ - United Kingdom

These are some examples, sir.

Comment: Are you asking how the tools work? Or how to do it without the tools? (I think you need the tools to do it)

Comment: Since hiding data inside an image is steganography by definition, I don't get what you mean by hiding files inside images without steganography tools.

Comment: @CodesInChaos i have to do without using tools

Comment: @xce how to do without the tools?

Comment: Just write your own code?

Comment: @LucasKauffman            yes sir i am a beginner guide me to write codes,i dont know how & where to start it from

Comment: have you ever programmed something, because otherwise you are a bit out of your league here...

Comment: I would have to agree with Lucas. I do have quite a bit of experience in programming, but I would say writing my own steganography tool is out of my league. If you are a beginner, not a good starting point.

Comment: "I don't know much about bridges, but can you tell me how to build a suspension bridge over the Thames to carry trucks? Would I need to use steel?"

Comment: sir i am a post graduate student i know programming in c,c++

Comment: as there are more answers why my post voted with -3?

Comment: By definition, hiding files inside an image is steganography. So what you're asking is how to write a steganography tool, apparently as a class assignment. We can't do your homework for you. You need to read those papers and get to work. If there is something you don't understand in those papers, or you get stuck at some point, feel free to ask a *specific* question.

Comment: @vignesh if you are a postgraduate student, this shouldn't be a very hard task. Just read the documents and answers and start working :)

Comment: This is one of the cases where "Read the source Luke" come to mind and just test for yourself.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is possible to hide files in other files. For pictures you can use the least significant bits of a RGB pixel definition.

A pixel has 3 bytes defining its color. Light Sea Green is defined by: 32,178,170 (R,G,B)

This translates to binary: 00100000,10101100,10101010

When we change the last bit of these, the color in an image does not change significantly. Therefor we can use the Least Significant bit of every color value of the pixel. This gives us 3 bits per pixel we can use.

So take a text, convert it to its binary representation and then write an algorithm that changes the LSB of every R,G and B value in the picture to the bit of that text. If you have a text of 128 bits long, you will need 128/3 pixels to hide that text.

Lets say I have a text who's binary representation is:

```
01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01010111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00100001 00100000
```

This text is 13 bytes long, meaning there are 13*8=104 bits. We know we can hide up to 3 bits in a pixel, so 104/3=  34.666, so we need 35 pixels.

So if we have a picture we'll use the first 35 pixels. To show you how it works, I'll give an example with two pixels. We can hide 6 bits in there, the first six bits of our text is `010010`

Our pixels are:

```
pixel1,R: 00010101
pixel1,G: 01011111
pixel1,B: 10111100

pixel 2,R: 10010001
pixel 2,G: 00010101
pixel 2,B: 11011100
```

Now we can just change the last bit for every color value to the representative bit of the text:

```
pixel1,R: 00010101 ---> 00010100 (changes to 0)
pixel1,G: 01011111 ---> 01011111 (remains the same)
pixel1,B: 10111100 ---> 10111100 (remains the same)

pixel 2,R: 10010001 ---> 10010000 (changes to 0)
pixel 2,G: 00010101 ---> 00010101 (remains the same)
pixel 2,B: 11011100 ---> 11011100 (remains the same)
```

If we want to extract the text from the image, we just look at the LSB of the new pixels, we get:

```
P1 R: 0
P1 G: 1
p1 B: 0

P2 R: 0
P2 G: 1
P2 B: 0
```

This is our row: 010010

Comment: Just don't store the image as a jpg :)

Comment: @monoceres Why?

Comment: @Abraham JPG uses lossy compression, this means that the exact RGB values will not be preserved after encoding, corrupting the encoded data.  Using a lossless format such as PNG is fine.

Answer (score 8):

Without using any steganography tool(!!)

In Windows:
create a .rar archive with the files that you want hide,
from a command prompt digit:

```
copy /b MYIMAGE.JPG + MYHIDDENFILE.RAR MYIMAGE.JPG
```

Done!
Use WinRar to access to the hidden files into JPG image.

Linux:
create a zip archive with the files that you want hide,

```
[tombo@palantir Immagini]$ zip TEXT.TXT.ZIP TEXT.TXT
```

hide the zip file in the image:

```
[tombo@palantir Immagini]$ cat MYIMAGE.JPG TEXT.TXT.ZIP > MYNEWIMAGE.JPG
```

Done!
Use unzip to access to the hidden files into JPG image:

```
[tombo@palantir Immagini]$ unzip MYNEWIMAGE.JPG
Archive: MYNEWIMAGE.JPG
warning [MYNEWIMAGE.JPG]:  5288 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
(attempting to process anyway)
inflating: TEXT.TXT
```

Comment: You haven't hidden anything. Naming an archive `MYIMAGE.JPG` does not make it an image any more than naming my cat Rover makes him a dog.

Comment: Sure, I know it perfectly! But the OS will show you the file as an image. If you double clik on the icon the OS will open it like an image. The question was... hide a file without steganography!

Comment: @Gilles Actually this does work, you just add bytes to the image, it's just not really that covert. But it doesn't answer the OP's question as these are still tools

Comment: @tombolinux without steganography tools, I think the OP has to do an assignment for school and needs to write his own tool.

Comment: I'll upvote.. it's a crappy answer, but it's an answer.

Comment: This works if the OP also doesn't require steganography ... if he still needs the file to be a picture or sound file, then your method doesn't apply.

Comment: This works because of quirks in the JPEG, Zip, and RAR file formats: a JPEG with garbage tacked on to the end of the file is still a valid JPEG; a RAR or Zip file with garbage tacked on to the beginning of the file is still a valid RAR or Zip.  If you glue a JPEG file to a RAR or Zip, you can change which half of the resulting file programs pay attention to by changing the extension.

Comment: Technically "cat" is a steganography tool here, because it's a tool that you're using for (very basic) steganography. So it's not actually a valid answer to the question (which is indeed unanswerable).

Answer (score 2):

Have you done research into the tools themselves to see how they work?:
https://github.com/Vsevak/stbmp

I simply did a search for steganography on github with a c++ filter.